# How to use GroupByKey on multiple keys in pyspark?

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, rdd

I have some data that looks like this:

```
([('01','A','2016-01-01','8701','123','2016-10-23'),('01','A','2016-
01-01','8701','123','2016-11-23'),('01','A','2016-01-01','8701','123','2016-12-23')])
```

My goal is to group by ('01','A','2016-01-01','8701','123') in PySpark and have it look like

```
[('01','A','2016-01-01''8701','123', ('2016-10-23', '2016-11-23', 
'2016-12-23'))]
```

I tried using groupByKey but didn't work for me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`groupBy` + `map`:

```
rdd = sc.parallelize(([('01','A','2016-01-01','8701','123','2016-10-23'),('01','A','2016-01-01','8701','123','2016-11-23'),('01','A','2016-01-01','8701','123','2016-12-23')]))

rdd.groupBy(lambda x: x[:-1]).map(lambda g: g[0] + (tuple(x[-1] for x in g[1]),)).collect()
# [('01', 'A', '2016-01-01', '8701', '123', ('2016-10-23', '2016-11-23', '2016-12-23'))]
```